# Writing a "\t" to a text file creates a line?

Tags: java, text-files, line-numbers

I'm writing to 2 textfiles and I wanted a eaiser way to read the textfiles without all the words and number laying to close to eachother so I chose to write them with a tab to seperate them. But when I do this my class `LineNumberReader` seems to think that the tab is a new line.

I have 2 classes. `TextWriting` and `compareTextFiles`

When I run my `TextWriting` class I can get an output that is like this:

> (1)       word1
>   (2)       word2
>   (3)       word3

So it is working as intended. (I used spaces for formatting purposes, but the file contains the tabs correctly)

And in my other class `compareTextFiles`I compare 2 textfiles that I wrote from the first class. The important code is this.

```
String word,word2;
int i;
lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));
while (sc.hasNext() && sc2.hasNext()) {                
    word = sc.next();
    word2 = sc2.next();                
    lnr.readLine();
    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(word2)) {
        i = lnr.getLineNumber();
        System.out.println("Line number: " + i + " and the word: [" + word + "]" + " and the word " + "[" + word2 + "]" + " is the same!");                    
    }
    else
        System.out.println("[" + word + "]" + " and " + "[" + word2 + "]" + " is not the same");
}
```

The output I am recieving is:

> Line number: 1 and the word: [(1)] and the word [(1)] is the same!
>   Line number: 2 and the word: [asd] and the word [asd] is the same!
>   Line number: 3 and the word: [(2)] and the word [(2)] is the same!
>   Line number: 3 and the word: [yeye] and the word [yeye] is the same!
>   Line number: 3 and the word: [(3)] and the word [(3)] is the same!
>   Line number: 3 and the word: [he] and the word [he] is the same!

Why does it get stuck on 3 so many times, and does *tab* create a new line of some sort?

Comment: Are you using a Scanner to scan the file AND a FileReader?

Comment: I recommend posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do the Scanner's use the default delimiter? How is the value from `getLineNumber` incremented?

Comment: What is `sc` set to ? Are there three lines in the file. Post a small working version that we can run to see the problem like @copeg said.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not really helping answering the question but yes I am.

Comment: @Shahzeb Yes there is 3 lines in the file at the moment, as I wrote in the description. (1)     word1
                   (2)     word2
                   (3)     word3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calls `LineNumberReader.readLine` for every scanner token. Presuming a) each Scanner uses the default delimiter  (in which case each line has 2 tokens) b) `LineNumberReader.readLine` increments the value returned by `LineNumberReader.getLineNumber` *until* the the file has been fully read - then for each token (rather than each line) it will increment until the 3 lines are read (and then stop incrementing), resulting in the output you get.

An alternative suggestion (there are many ways to skin this cat): consider using only the 2 Scanner's to read the files, reading the files using the `Scanner.readLine` method. For each line, increment a variable representing the line number and then parse the lines as needed.

```
int lineCount = 0;
while ( sc.hasNextLine() && sc2.hasNextLine() ){
    lineCount++;
    String line1 = sc.nextLine();
    String line2 = sc2.nextLine();
    //parse the lines
    String[] line1tabs = line1.split("\t");
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: But why does it stop incrementing at 3? Shouldn't it increment from 3 to 4,5,6,7,8 etc ?

Comment: Is there a way with scanner to read the line with and get 2 tokens, but still use `LineNumberReader` to just read each line and increment it ?